Wordpress WP_Query meta_query compare LIKE returning %LIKE%
My Query arguments;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
             'key'      => 'partner',
             'value'    => $partner,
             'compare'  => 'LIKE',
          ),
    ),
 );

If my value for $partner="561"this query also returns Posts where $partner="5614"
Setting 'compare' => '=' or 'compare' =>'INCLUDE' returns nothing.
Where is my misunderstanding?
Note that due to the vagaries of ACF 'value' could either be an array or a string. And this also successfully returns a post where $partner= array("561","21423")
at the moment I am testing the results with if ( in_array($partner, get_field('partner')) )  but that's clumsy.

Printing the Query object request property reveals this;  "wp0_7_postmeta.meta_key = 'partner' AND wp0_7_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '{527fcbe1b80d5713c78a1e865fb1e035a46b37e8a1c995859715208fe7a91fe3}561{527fcbe1b80d5713c78a1e865fb1e035a46b37e8a1c995859715208fe7a91fe3}'" (my bold) which I have no idea how to interpret

It seems to be working as intended though? When you query for stuff using LIKE it'll return stuff that's similar or equal to what you asked, hence 561 and 5614. What exactly are you trying to do?

NOT TESTED, but doesn't it about the field type ?
In meta_query the default value of type is 'CHAR'
(Doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#usage)
And by extension, maybe the comparison is not strict.
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'      => 'partner',
            'value'    => $partner,
            'compare'  => 'LIKE',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC' // <--- add this line
        ),
    ),
);


I think your problem may be stemming from the instances where 'value' is an array. From the docs:

value (string|array) – Custom field value. It can be an array only
when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'. You don’t
have to specify a value when using the 'EXISTS' or 'NOT EXISTS'
comparisons in WordPress 3.9 and up.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments
